# CSS animation not working when directly copied from demo

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to use a CSS (buzz out) animation as can be seen [here](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/#effects).

Works perfectly in the demo, I have copied the relevant CSS and can't get it to work on a website so I even made a simple [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zigojacko/z14bp7qx/) and it still doesn't work.

Please can someone point out what I am evidently missing as this is all the CSS seems to contain and I am a bit baffled to how it is working with the same style declaration on the demo but not in the jsFiddle.

Code snippet included below as well as at jsFiddle.

```css
[class^="hvr-"] {
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    margin: .4em;
    padding: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #e1e1e1;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.hvr-buzz-out {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.hvr-buzz-out:hover, .hvr-buzz-out:focus, .hvr-buzz-out:active {
    -webkit-animation-name: hvr-buzz-out;
    animation-name: hvr-buzz-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hvr-buzz-out">Buzz Out</a>
```

Comment: `hvr-buzz-out` is not actually in your code as an animation (we are looking for `@keyframes hvr-buzz-out {}`). Without the keyframes, there is no animation defined.

Comment: Haha - thank you - yes, I see what else I need now. Doh. :)

Comment: No prob, I posted it as an answer in the meanwhile :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need the `@keyframes` that define the animation:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes hvr-buzz-out {
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }

  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0);
    transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
    transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-buzz-out {
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }

  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0);
    transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
    transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
  }
}

[class^="hvr-"] {
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    margin: .4em;
    padding: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #e1e1e1;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.hvr-buzz-out {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.hvr-buzz-out:hover, .hvr-buzz-out:focus, .hvr-buzz-out:active {
    -webkit-animation-name: hvr-buzz-out;
    animation-name: hvr-buzz-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hvr-buzz-out">Buzz Out</a>
```

They were also in the CSS file above the code you already had.